# Exporting ContentVersion to ESB

Tags: integration, contentversion, architecture

We are currently designing an integration for exporting 20-50 Salesforce Files to an external system through our ESB.

Our current plan is to send the record information and associated ContentVersion Id's to the ESB via JSON POST. The ESB will then call into Salesforce and pull out the VersionData and associated fields (VersionNumber, etc.) from the ContentVersions and send over to the external system.

What are the pros and cons to this approach vs. sending over the VersionData from Salesforce rather than the ESB calling in and GETting it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you're using is the right way to do it.

What I like most is that it allows you to control your interactions with SF in your ESB where you are likely less limited in terms of resources. Since SF has quite a few governor limits, shifting the load off of Salesforce and splitting your calls to SF into multiple contexts you'll avoid most of these limits.

That being said, I believe pro/con type questions or questions that lead to discussions are frowned upon on this site. I'd avoid asking them in the future.

Comment: I agree - the heap size limit looms in the distance with the other approach.